# usb stick doesn't connect to my laptop anymore after removing /dev/sda1

Tags: usb

I accidentally removed */dev/sda1* and now my usb stick **doesn't** connect to my laptop.

I've already tried to make a new /dev/sda1 but it doesnt work.

Now i'm using the testdisk command to repair it, hope it works...

Comment: Try rebooting, reformatting the drive, and if that doesn't help, the better site to ask on is https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use mknod command to recreate the missing device. See the major number of your sda disk:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Dec 11 11:21 /dev/sda
                       ^
                       |
      This is the number you are looking at
```

Now you can create a device for the first partition on this device, it will have the same major number and the minor number of 1:

```
$ sudo mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1
```

The first parameter is the name of the device, the second 'b' means it's a block device, the last two parameters are the major and the minor numbers of the new device.

Comment: I did that, and it seems to work but nothing appears in my dolphin file browser and i have already disconnected and then reconnected the usb device but it still don't seems to work.

Comment: Well, for dynamic automount of your USB device you need a correctly working udev. There are several steps in the process, which you can check out. For example, you can start with `dmesg` command to see if the device is detected when you plug it in. Then you can check if you can mount it manually, then check udev configuration, etc. The specifics depends on the distribution which you are using.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 KDE Plasma desktop